# Can't get a simple broadcast with graphql-ruby subscriptions working

Tags: actioncable, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-ruby

I have a barebones setup for update broadcasts with graphql-ruby over Action Cable.

- The client receives the initial payload on subscription fine.
- The client isn't receiving any updates and the `update` method of the subscription type isn't being called. No errors on the backend. The trigger call seems to be silently ignored. This is what I'm trying to troubleshoot / properly understand how it's supposed to work.

The docs I'm looking at:

- https://graphql-ruby.org/subscriptions/subscription_classes.html
- https://graphql-ruby.org/subscriptions/triggers

The subscription type:

```rb
module Types
  class SubscriptionType < Types::BaseObject
    field :server_info, subscription: Subscriptions::ServerInfoSubscription, null: false
  end
end
```

```rb
module Subscriptions
  class ServerInfoSubscription < Subscriptions::BaseSubscription
    field :date_time, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: false

    def subscribe
      { date_time: DateTime.now }
    end

    def update
      puts 'UPDATE CALLED' # Nope, it's not being called
      super
    end
  end
end
```

The way I'm attempting to trigger an update:

```rb
MySchema.subscriptions.trigger(:server_info, {}, { date_time: DateTime.now })
```

The schema is defined as:

```rb
class MySchema < GraphQL::Schema
  use GraphQL::Execution::Interpreter
  use GraphQL::Subscriptions::ActionCableSubscriptions

  subscription(Types::SubscriptionType)
end
```

I am using the redis adapter for the development environment in config/cable.yml:

```yaml
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: test-app_development
```

What am I missing? Any troubleshooting tips?

**Update:**

Some diagnostics:

Rails logs for the initial (and successful) subscription call:

```
GraphqlChannel#execute({"query"=>"subscription ServerInfoSubscription {\n  serverInfo {\n    dateTime\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n", "variables"=>{}, "operationName"=>"ServerInfoSubscription"})
GraphqlChannel transmitting {"data"=>{"serverInfo"=>{"dateTime"=>"2020-10-08T10:47:08-04:00", "__typename"=>"ServerInfoSubscriptionPayload"}}}
GraphqlChannel is streaming from graphql-subscription:9087735b-9b99-4d66-8b77-ff3622c8efe7
GraphqlChannel is streaming from graphql-event::dateTime:
Started POST "/graphql" for 192.168.64.210 at 2020-10-08 10:47:08 -0400
```

Checking active Redis PubSub channels:

```
$ redis-cli -h 192.168.64.210 -p 6379 pubsub channels
1) "test-app_development:graphql-subscription:9087735b-9b99-4d66-8b77-ff3622c8efe7"
2) "test-app_development:graphql-event::dateTime:"
3) "_action_cable_internal"
```

Outcome of running the trigger call in the Rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> MySchema.subscriptions.trigger(:server_info, {}, { date_time: DateTime.now })
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to graphql-event::serverInfo:: "{\"date_time\":\"2020-10-08T10:54:18-04:00\",\"__sym_keys__\":[\"date_time\"]}"
```

The thing that stands out as obvious is that the Redis PubSub channel is called "graphql-event::dateTime:" while the trigger call broadcasts over the nonexistent "graphql-event::serverInfo:" channel. I do not understand why the actual Redis channel is called "graphql-event::dateTime" while the subscription query is on the top-level "ServerInfo" type.

Comment: If you had actually subscribed to the query sucessfully, I would expect `redis-cli` to show you something like `test-app_development:graphql-subscription:UUID:serverInfo`. I think you may need to add `extend GraphQL::Subscriptions::SubscriptionRoot` inside your `SubscriptionType` class.

Comment: @Unixmonkey I had it in the base subscription class. But graphql-ruby was logging a warning saying it no longer needs to be included. So I removed it. That wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working, but couldn't pinpoint why this wasn't working:

```rb
MySchema.subscriptions.trigger(:server_info, {}, { date_time: DateTime.now })
```

Note that I had been passing an empty hash (`{}`) as the second argument.

The way I got it working is to add an `argument` to my query and use a matching argument (matching to the original subscription query). Something like this:

```rb
module Subscriptions
  class EventReceivedSubscription < Subscriptions::BaseSubscription
    argument :event_name, String, required: true

    field :event_name, String, null: false
    field :payload, String, null: true
  end
end
```

```rb
MySchema.subscriptions.trigger(
  :event_received,
  { event_name: 'greeting' },
  { payload: 'Hello' }
)
```

The Redis channel I can now see is:

```sh
$ redis-cli -h 192.168.64.210 -p 6379 pubsub channels
1) "test-app_development:graphql-event::eventReceived:eventName:greeting"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the method which you are trying to overwrite is expecting parameters, if you look at the `GraphQL::Schema::Subscription`

```rb
def subscribe( attrs = {})
...
end

def update( attrs = {} )
...
end
```

You can safely remove the `:argument` and define **your** update method with parameter which will solve the issue.

```
def update( _attrs = {} )
  # your logic here
end
```